# Determine number of row spans given a start index and a length

Tags: algorithm

I have a matrix start index of my data and the number of elements of my data
and I need to find the number of rows that the data span.
e.g. the matrix

```
 0              5 
-------------------
|  |  |  |  |x |x |  
-------------------
|x |x |x |x |x |x |  
-------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  
-------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  
-------------------
```

My data is marked with x. I know the start index 4, the length of the data 8.
And I need to determine the number of rows this data spans, 2 in this case. (just doing length/6 is off by one in many cases, surely there have to be a simple formula for this..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only know `offset` (i.e. index of the starting column), `size` (i.e. how many data), `cols` (i.e. maximum number of colums), and you want to calculate how many rows your data will span, you can do

```
int get_spanned_rows(int offset, int size, int cols) {
  int spanned_rows = (offset + size) / cols
  if ( ( (offset + size ) % cols) != 0 )
    spanned_rows++
  return spanned_rows
}
```

where `%` is the modulus (or reminder) operator

Comment: You should subtract one from `size` in order to get inclusive `end_row`/`end_col`. Otherwise you'll get one row too much in some cases.

Comment: I only know cols, size and offset though, not start_row and start_col (they just happened to be 0 and 4 in this case)

Comment: @Howard, @Lyke: I've edited my answer to take into account *Lyke* requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
int calc_rows(int start,int length){
    int rows = 0;
    int x= 0;
    if (start != 0){
        x = 6%start;
        rows+=1;
    }
    if ((start+length) % 6 != 0){
        x +=(start+length) % 6;
        rows+=1;
    }
    rows+= (length - x)/6;
    return rows;
}
```

calculates number of rows by dividing by 6 but after subtracting partially filled rows count

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want the number of rows you can calculate

```
num_rows = (offset + size + cols - 1) / cols
```

which in this case is

```
num_rows = (4 + 8 + 6 - 1) / 6 = 17 / 6 = 2
```